# How to filter entities based on 2nd degree relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm using EntityFramework Core with a database schema that simplifies to this:

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Include { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public int FromID { get; set; }
    public int ToID { get; set; }
}
```

Where the Parent is linked to the child by an entry in a third table.
Parent to Link is one-to-many
Link to Child is one-to-one

I'm unable to change the database schema as part of this work.

I am trying to return instances of Parent that are linked to at least one child and where ALL children meet a certain criteria (in this example `include == true`)

I've tried a lot of different queries, including the one below which works in this test scenario but doesn't seem to scale well.

```cs
var ParentList = new[]
{
    new Parent {ID = 1}, //3 children, 1 fails criteria
    new Parent {ID = 2}, //2 children, all pass criteria
    new Parent {ID = 3}  //no children
};
var ChildList = new[]
{
    new Child {ID = 11, Include = true},
    new Child {ID = 12, Include = true},
    new Child {ID = 13, Include = false},
    new Child {ID = 21, Include = true},
    new Child {ID = 22, Include = true},
};
var LinkList = new[]
{
    new Link {FromID = 1, ToID = 11},
    new Link {FromID = 1, ToID = 12},
    new Link {FromID = 1, ToID = 13},
    new Link {FromID = 2, ToID = 21},
    new Link {FromID = 2, ToID = 22},
};

var relevant = (from parent in ParentList
    join l in LinkList on parent.ID equals l.FromID into links
    from linkedChildren in (
        from link in links
        join child in ChildList on link.ToID equals child.ID into children
        from child in children
        group child by link.FromID into kids
        select kids.AsEnumerable())
    where linkedChildren.All(x => x.Include)
    select new { parent, linkedChildren }).ToList();

Assert.Single(relevant);
Assert.Equal(2, relevant.First().parent.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either one of these should point you in the right direction

```
ParentList.Where(s => s.LinkList .Any(e => e.ChildList.Include == true))

from s in dc.ParentList
from e in s.LinkList 
where e.ChildList.Include == true
select s;
```

See if this better matches what you need:

```
var result = from l in LinkList
             join p in ParentList on l.FromID equals p.ID
             join c in ChildList on l.ToID equals c.ID and c.Include == true
             select new { p.ID, c.ID, l.FromID, l.ToID};
```

Comment: in my case the ID fields in `Parent` and `Child` are not foreign keys in `Link` (link is a sort of generic way to link to many different tables). So in my model `Parent` doesn't have a `LinkList` property and similarly `Link` doesn't have a `ChildList` property which is why I'm manually joining the collections.

Comment: @Sbaldwin I changed my answer. It should match your requirements now.

Comment: that updated answer returns a record for each link between a parent and an 'include==true' child. What I need is a result set of any parent entities where _all_ children are 'include==true'.